# How can I access all my zaps or a specific zap using Zapier's API?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I searched the documents but couldn't go further than the webhooks documents. What I am looking for is an api where I can see all my zaps or the detail of a zap. Is there such access on Zapier? As far as I understand I can't see this data with webhooks. Can you help with this? Am I overlooking something?

I reviewed webhooks and partner documents.